# How to show external subtitles with React Native Video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a video file and also separate `srt` and `vtt` files. How do I show the subtitles using `react-native-video`?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example from the react-native-video [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video)

```
import { TextTrackType }, Video from 'react-native-video';

textTracks={[
  {
    title: "English CC",
    language: "en",
    type: TextTrackType.VTT, // "text/vtt"
    uri: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/subtitles/subtitles_en.vtt"
  },
  {
    title: "Spanish Subtitles",
    language: "es",
    type: TextTrackType.SRT, // "application/x-subrip"
    uri: "https://durian.blender.org/wp-content/content/subtitles/sintel_es.srt"
  }
]}
```